# Error when importing Intents in Xcode 8 beta

Tags: ios, xcode8, sirikit

I can't seem to compile my Intents and IntentsUI extensions in Xcode 8.

I haven't changed anything in the class templates, and I am getting error like below.

[image]

Comment: Did you try cleaning up your project and deleting derived data?

Comment: @Jelly Yeah, I have.

Comment: Also make sure Intents is added as framework to the project and there are no name conflicts (you have some other thing named Intents).